# Button is not accessible and not focused on tab key

Tags: html, css, accessibility, multi-select, sumoselect.js

I have below code to show buttons in a multi select dropdown. I have used tabindex="0" for each

tag. Also added focus in CSS.

```css
.btn-clear-all:focus {
  outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 1px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group-multi__MultiControls">
<p tabindex="0" class="btn-tertiary--light">Cancel</p>
<p tabindex="0" class="btn-clear-all">Clear all</p>
<p tabindex="0" class="btn-secondary">Apply</p>
</div>
```

My problem here is 'Cancel' button is accessible on tab key, but not other two - Clear all and Apply.

Comment: I am able to focus on all the links if I run your code snippet

Comment: pretty sure looking at your CSS "Clear All" is the one where you would see your custom focus indicator, not "Cancel". Other than the fact **you should use a `<button>` element** for accessibility and so you don't have to worry about `tabindex="0"` you need to change your CSS selector to be `.btn-tertiary--light:focus,  .btn-clear-all:focus, .btn-secondary:focus{`. Also if this is bootstrap (which it looks to be) then you should add the `.btn` class as well to each button so you can simply target that instead in your CSS `class="btn btn-tertiary--light"` etc. allows you to just do `.btn{`.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing an extremely obvious thing (I mean, for semantics and accessibility).
Look at your buttons and pay attention to what you see. Do you see *buttons*?

Correct answer: No. You see *paragraphs* (`<p>`s, not `<button>`s).

There are two solutions, one best and one not so good:

1. **The best solution**. Change all of your `<p>`s to `<button>`s. You already have Bootstrap's `btn-secondary` class applied to them, so I'm pretty confident your styling won't suffer in any way.
2. Add `role="button"` to your `<p>`s. Again, as the first rule of ARIA states that you mustn't use ARIA if you absolutely haven't to, it's a not too good solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group-multi__MultiControls">
<button type="button" tabindex="0" class="btn-tertiary--light">Cancel</button >
<button type="button"  tabindex="0" class="btn-clear-all">Clear all</button>
<button type="button" tabindex="0" class="btn-secondary">Apply</button>
</div>

This might help.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).